# Projeto Maven no SVN

Tags: maven, svn

Possuo a seguinte estrutura de projetos Maven na minha workspace:

- sistema (com o POM configurado para consolidar todos os projetos abaixo)
- DAO
- EAR
- MODEL
- WEB
- VO

Estou desenvolvendo em parceria e optamos por utilizar o SVN.

Gostaria de saber qual o melhor processo para commitar o projeto pela primeira vez e como deve ser feito o checkout.

Alguem poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A opção mais fácil é utilizando o cliente [tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), que se integra no seu sistema operativo. Nele tem a opção **import**, que importará o seu código para o URL do seu repositório SVN. Tenha atenção em definir primeiro a lista de exceções do tortoise, para que ele não importe todos os ficheiros tais como dll, exe, bak, sln etc.

Depois faça o **checkout** do repositório para a pasta do seu projeto, para que o tortoise crie a estrutura de versionamento do código. A partir dá pode começar a trabalhar com o seu repositório fazendo commits e updates.

Também pode utilizar outro cliente SVN tal como o [Smartsvn](http://www.smartsvn.com/) ou o [Ankhsvn](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).
Também pode utilizar a [linha de comandos](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html) para efetuar estas operações.

Comment: Entendi, mas devo subir todos os projetos ou só o raiz? Estou usando o CloudForge para repositório.

Comment: No repositório deve ter todos os projetos em que pretende colaborar.